# Phonegap application : Timeout issue

Tags: ajax, cordova

The scenario is like this.

For testing purpose we also created a test service 
if the service take 7 sec or more to respond phonegap app shows “ Requested page not found 404"
Else it works fine.

Any ideas?

call is like

```
$.ajax({
    url: arrUrl[0],
    method: "GET",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: Obj,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    timeout:90000,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#dvresult").html(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //Notification(2);
        IsException = true;
        var strResponse = "";
        strResponse = ajaxExceptionHandling(xhr, ajaxOptions);
        alert(strResponse);
        //ErrorMessageDB("Login", "GetServerDateTime", "A_iStaffDId, A_strGUID", "GetServerDateTime:Fetching data from server", strResponse, localStorage.EmployeesKId4LastModifiedBy);
    }
});
```

Please see the timeout is set as 90 sec now.The call in safari at the same time is popping the data everytime.But when tried from phonegap the issue appears

More info

arrUrl[0] is absolute url..

Tried the whitelisting still it occours..

One more finding...

Day time the issue appears...at night its fine..we are using a load balancer...is there something in here causing the trouble that the service get 404 as response.Android is getting the responses for the same codebase

Its only phonegap + ios causing the trouble !

Comment: arrUrl[0] is absolute or relative url? did you whitelist the urls?

Comment: absolute url..Tried the whitelisting still it occours..One more finding...Day time the issue appears...at night its fine..we are using a load balancer...is there something in here causing the trouble that the service get 404 as response.Android is getting the responses for the same codebase

Comment: if it works at nights, then it seems more like a server problem. How did you whitelist? try with *

Comment: yes it is done like that.In staging it works fine..but production it causes problem